# How to prevent a user from accessing the site when he/she Copy and paste the url address to get in to the site?

Tags: java, web-services, servlet-filters

How to prevent a user from accessing the site when he/she Copy and paste the url address to get in to the site.They should only login to get to the site.If they have already logged in and then copy the url and paste it in new window i stop them getting into the site.

Answer (score 2):

Have a authentication [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) that checks if user is authenticates when she tries to access restricted area

Comment: He doesn't even want them to access if they are authenticated and copy/pasted the url ...

Comment: *when he/she Copy and paste the url address to get in to the site.* @Meena can you please clarify

Comment: The way I understand it is not quite the same: I think, the poster wants to prevent a logged-in user from copying the URL and reopen it in an unauthenticated session (like a new window (even though, that a new window is not a new session!)).

Comment: I come to the same conclusion as nfechner.

Comment: @cularis  now I am confused:) , meena can you clarify ??

Comment: yes, i also want to prevent the logged in user from just copy the url and paste it in the new browser and reopen it.

Comment: well you **can't** prevent user from copying URL, but you can have some server side session data to track if user has opened this page don't allow her to open this page again from new tab or something..

Comment: will you please explain me..How to implement this

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: You could use some one-time tokens in the URL itself, but this is tricky as well and I'm sure it's possible to get around... to be honest: what's the rationale for this requirement? Do you want the user to not have more than one window open?

Comment: My actual requirement is User shouldnt get access to page if he try to copy and paste the url(which he already opned a session using login credentials) in another browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check The referer field of the request header. On the front page accept all, and on the deeper pages only accept requests originating from within the site.

Comment: Referer is easily spoofed so is not a reliable check.

Comment: I thought he was tryi g to make it inconvenient to deep link, not impossible. To make it impossible I guess you could use some form of token system where a token for navigation is generated on the first page and validated on the target page.